# how to copy flask dependencies from one stage to the next one in a Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am learning about Docker and I have a Dockerfile with a simple app such as this:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP App.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT :3001
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev
COPY ./myapp/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -vv -r requirements.txt
ADD ./myapp .
EXPOSE 3001
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

I want to use multistage to have a smaller image, so checking this https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/ I have change my Dockerfile to this:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine as builder
COPY ./myapp/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.8-alpine
ADD ./myapp .
COPY --from=builder /root/.local /root/.local
ENV PATH=/root/.local:$PATH
ENV FLASK_APP App.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT 3000
CMD ["python", "-m", "flask", "run"]
```

But when running the container I get an error telling me the MySQL dp dependecy is not installed (it is in requirements.txt), but it is within the requirements.txt file and in the first Dockerfile works, so I do not know what I am missing as if I get it right the COPY step in the second stage should copy the dependencies installed in the first stage right?. This is the output I get when trying to spin the container:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: Error loading shared library libmariadb.so.3: No such file or directory (needed by /root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Comment: If you analyze carefully the link you provided you can see that from `compile-image` it has copied the **build result** not the libraries. You must think the builder step like this: "Get all libs necessary to compile, and build, then on 2nd stage get the build output"

Comment: hmmmm I do not get it TBH... what I actually like to achieve is to get a cleaner image in the second stage just with my app (which does not need to compile) and the required libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev` also install MariaDB libraries, which you don't install in the final image. Their lack is the cause of the errors you get.

Comment: it sorted it out. Thanks a lot for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Is mysql getting installed from requirements.txt or is it installed by apk MariahDb? If the latter then that’s what is missing in the second image; it’s not pip installed —-user under .local it’s installed systemwide in the first image but not in the second.

Comment: flask_mysqldb is installed from the requirements.txt file